# custom dialog preventing browser navigation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dialog

As Rie819 has pointed out, this is a duplicate question. However, the other post does not discuss how to create a custom Dialog with this feature. With that being said, I will revise my question and ask for tips on how to do this.

---

Alright, so I've looked in the MSDN library and also attempted to find the solution to this elsewhere, but I seem to be missing something here....

So my issues are while using OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog, I want the user to be restricted to a specific folder, so they can only save/open there. In other words, they cannot browse away from the InitialDirectory I've setup.

Is there a simple value I'm missing that sets this? If it's an obvious solution I'm going to kick myself for this one....

Thanks in advance,

Comment: duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635846/c-sharp-openfiledialog-lock-to-directory

Comment: Thank you, rie819. With that being said, is there a similar post discussing a custom Dialog with this feature?

Comment: Not sure, but it should be pretty quick to whip up.  Create a form that has the elements you want then display it in a modal manner. You can read the file directory from the config file and away you go.  Is there a particular part that you would like elaborated?

Comment: I don't believe so, was just curious that it wasn't already a post somewhere. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: ....actually yes. Can I not upvote you for a comment? Or close this question/mark it answered?

Comment: Added an answer so you can mark it if you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate question.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635846/c-sharp-openfiledialog-lock-to-directory) for resolution.

Essentially you have two options.  1 - catch if the user changes the directory.  2 - Create your own custom save dialog box.